# WSL2 error: _tkinter.TclError: couldn't connect to display "127.0.0.1:0.0"

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, visual-studio-code, wsl-2

I have this error when run my python file: `_tkinter.TclError: couldn't connect to display "127.0.0.1:0.0"`.

I mention that I am running VSCODE in WSL2 distro and Windows Pylance installed along with `tkinter` last version.
In my ZSH terminal I have added this line as it is recommended by Microsoft for WSL2: `export DISPLAY=$(grep -m 1 nameserver /etc/resolv.conf | awk '{print $2}'):0.0`. Commands like `export DISPLAY=:0` doesn't work at all on WSL2.

Many thanks for any help,
vhij

LE: I have Windows 11 with Ubuntu 20.04 LTS distro, Xming and VcXsrv.

Answer (score 1):

I have solved now after many trials and combinations, but it works now:

`$ nano ~/.zshrc`

Copied this 2 lines:

> export DISPLAY=$(awk '/nameserver / {print $2; exit}' /etc/resolv.conf 2>/dev/null):0
> export LIBGL_ALWAYS_INDIRECT=1

`$ source ~/.zshrc`

Then in Windows: open XLaunch: Multiple windows -> Start no client -> Check 'Disable access control' -> Finish.

After that, I went on Windows Defender Firewall with Advanced Security and made 'green' status to all of VcXsrv and Xming X Server in Inbound Rules: Properties -> Allow the connection -> OK. (I have tried to add in Scope  -> Remote IP address -> These IP addressess -> 172.72.0.1, but it didn't worked).

[image]

[image]

Then I run the python script successfully and tkinter window pop-up.

Comment: Good to hear you got it working.